# How to add text inside video like http://www.helpjanff.nl/

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, actionscript

Please look at this site http://www.helpjanff.nl/

First field name, second field email and third field mobile no please enter it the click on the Verstuur button. Then the video plays which shows your name in the card and mobile .

How can we pass custom variable like that in flash video in actionscript. Can somebody tell me about it ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a predefined video. You know its size. You know where is a place for text. So there is no problem to add a `TextField` instance over an instance of the `Video` class with the custom text.